# How to compute coordinates of a point that intersects an sphere

Tags: analytic-geometry, spheres

[image: scenario]

Hi all.

Is there a way to compute the S(x,y,z), given the following information:

A(x,y,z)

e = elevation (from the line AS)

Az = azimuth (over A). Perpendicular to x axis. Can vary from 0 tp 360.

R = Radius of Earth (appr. 6378.1363)

h = height of S (in kilometers)

EARTH CENTER = origin of the system O(0, 0, 0)

Can anyone help me? I'm writing the code using python, if it is helpful.

Rgds

Comment: How is your definition of the Elevation e?

Comment: What are the knowns? What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I'd like to calculate the coordinates of S(X,Y,Z).
The elevation (e) is the angle between the the perpendicular plane of x axis and the S.

Comment: What are you given? Are you saying that the coordinates $x,y,z$ of $A$ are known, and the angle $e$, and the angle ACS? Or is $h$ known and not the angle ACS?

Comment: Sorry about the figure. The angle ACS is not given. H is given.

Comment: You do not have enough information. Think of $CA$ as an axis and rotate everything about that. The point $S$ will describe a circle about the axis, so its coordinates will vary.

Comment: Ok. I changed the problem and now the system can rotate on A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the angle $e$ and the point $S$ lie in the same plane as the line $x=z=0$ and the point $A$, use the law of Cosines with angle $\theta=\angle ACS$:

$$\frac {|AS|}{\cos \theta}=\frac{R+h}{\cos\left(\frac \pi 2+e\right)}=\frac{R+h}{\sin(e)}=\frac{R}{\cos\left(\pi-\frac\pi 2-\theta-e\right)}=\frac{R}{\sin(\theta+e)}$$

This is three equations with two unknowns, and in particular we can solve for $\theta$ easily as

$$\sin(\theta+e)=\frac{R\sin(e)}{R+h}\\
\theta=\arcsin\left(\frac{R\sin(e)}{R+h}\right)-e$$

We should also get the angle $\phi$ between the lines $x=z=0$ and $\vec {CA}$ as this will make other vector calculations easier.  Using the notation $A=(X_A,Y_A,Z_A)$ for the coordinates at point $A$, we get

$$\phi=\arccos\left(\frac{Y_A}{\sqrt{X_A^2+Y_A^2+Z_A^2}}\right)$$

We have assumed that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are angles in the same plane, so now we have an angle and a length of travel and we can identify the point $S$ by these...  But note that we have to use a ratio of the $X_A$ and $Z_A$ coordinates to help with this process since we cannot otherwise distinguish between them.  The $Y_S$ coordinate is direct:

$$Y_S=(R+h)\cos(\theta+\phi)$$

The other two are as follows:

$$X_S=\frac{X_A}{\sqrt{X_A^2+Z_A^2}}(R+h)\sin(\theta+\phi)$$
$$Z_S=\frac{Z_A}{\sqrt{X_A^2+Z_A^2}}(R+h)\sin(\theta+\phi)$$